# Javascript sort a string array by last name

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting

I have an array:

```
arr4=["John Alpha","Allen Beta", "Elle Cappa"];
```

I have a sort function that sorts a string array into descending order

```
function getSize(arr){
return arr.length;
}

function sortStringArrDes(arr){
arrSize=getSize(arr);
var temp;
for(j=0; j<arrSize-1; j++){
    for(i=0; i<arrSize-1; i++){
        if (arr[i] < arr[i+1]){
            temp = arr[i+1];
            arr[i+1] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Can I sort the array by surname using the sortStringArrDes or is there another, less complex way to do this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here I use `.split(' ')[1]` to get the lastname for the condition and it looks like it would work.

```js
arr4=["John Alpha","Allen Beta", "Elle Cappa"];

function sortStringArrDes(arr){
arrSize=arr.length;
var temp;
for(j=0; j<arrSize-1; j++){
    for(i=0; i<arrSize-1; i++){
        if (arr[i].split(' ')[1] < arr[i+1].split(' ')[1]){
            temp = arr[i+1];
            arr[i+1] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

console.log(sortStringArrDes(arr4))
```

Comment: hey I benchmarked this, it's faster than  `.sort`.  I mistaken thought not.  If you make a small edit here, I can upvote, thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Rather than trying to reinvent the wheel, you might consider using the native `Array.prototype.sort` method:

```js
const arr4 = ["John Alpha", "Elle Cappa", "Allen Beta"];
arr4.sort((a, b) => b.split(' ')[1].localeCompare(a.split(' ')[1]));
console.log(arr4);
```

[`.localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) returns an integer representing whether the called string or the passed string comes first alphabetically.

Comment: Just a side note, when split the array, maybe you should take care to join all the elements again except the first in case there exists compound surnames.

Comment: `localeCompare()` is a nice touch!

Comment: To sort by the number use  `(a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, undefined, {'numeric': true})`the undefined variable is for the Locale String

Answer (score 4):

Here's a one liner

```
arr4.sort(x => arr4.map(y => y.split(' ')[1]) ).reverse()
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution to this problem can be aproached with [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) in conjunction with [String.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and the already mentioned [String.localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare). Note this will also work if you have compound surnames.

```js
const input = ["John Alpha", "Elle Cappa", "Allen Beta", "Rob Collyses Chung"];

input.sort(
    (a, b) => b.match(/\s(.+)/)[1].localeCompare(a.match(/\s(.+)/)[1])
);

console.log(input);
```

Even more, you should also note that `Array.sort()` will mutate your original array, if you don't want that to happen, you can create a copy of the array before sort it using [Array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice). Example:

```js
const input = ["John Alpha", "Elle Cappa", "Allen Beta", "Rob Collyses Chung"];

let res = input.slice().sort(
    (a, b) => b.match(/\s(.+)/)[1].localeCompare(a.match(/\s(.+)/)[1])
);

console.log("Original is not mutated: ", input);
console.log("Sorted copy: ", res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a compare function like below and use [`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to sort by last name

```js
var names = ["Allen Beta", "John Alpha", "Elle Cappa"];
var sortedNames = names.sort(compare);
console.log(sortedNames);

function compare(a, b) {
  var splitA = a.split(" ");
  var splitB = b.split(" ");
  var lastA = splitA[splitA.length - 1];
  var lastB = splitB[splitB.length - 1];

  if (lastA < lastB) return -1;
  if (lastA > lastB) return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use two for loops, split each array item, reverse it and sort it. Then reverse it once sorted and join it back together. See code below:

```js
var arr4=["Allen Beta", "John Alpha", "Elle Cappa"];
var arr5 = []; // Keep the original array as is.
for(var i = 0; i <  arr4.length; i++){
 arr5[i] = arr4[i].split(" ").reverse().join(" ");
}
arr5.sort();
for(var i = 0; i < arr5.length; i++){
 arr5[i] = arr5[i].split(" ").reverse().join(" ");
}

console.log(arr5); // a b c
console.log(arr5.reverse()); // c b a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Try this way    

    let arr = [`John Alpha`,`Allen Beta`,`Elle Cappa`];
    let new_arr=arr.map(item=>{
        return item.split(' ');
    })
    let sorting = new_arr.sort((a,b)=>{
        return b[b.length-1].localeCompare(a[a.length-1]);
    })
    let merging= sorting.map(item=>{
        return item.join(' ');
    })
    console.log(merging)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

    let arr = [`John Alpha`,`Allen Beta`,`Elle Cappa`];

    var newarr=[];

    for(x=0;x<arr.length;x++){
    var z=arr[x].split(" ");
    var z=z.reverse();
    newarr[x]=z;
    }

var v=newarr.sort();

var v=v.reverse();

    console.log(v);

<!-- end snippet -->
```